# solution to the parabolic pde with nonlinear source

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am considering the following parabolic equation

$$\begin{cases} u_t-\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}=-u^3,& x\in \mathbb{R},t\in (0,2]\\
u(0,x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(x+2)), &x\in \mathbb{R}.\end{cases}$$

I am wondering whether we can solve the problem with a classic solution.

Since I am not sure what the exact solution to the PDE is, I use some numerical method to solve the problem. The following picture plots the numerical solution for some particular time points.

[image]

It seems that the exact solution is given by a separable form $u(t,x)=A(t)\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}(x+2))$ with $A(t)$ decreases. But I plug it into the PDE and find it never holds. May I know whether this is due to my numerical solution is not correct? What should the exact solution to the problem look like?

Comment: At late times the $u^3$ term will be very small compared to the left hand side so if we just ignore it then we obtain a solution on the form you have with $A(t) \propto e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{8}t}$. Note that this will only be an approximation to the solution and the full solution will be more complicated.

Comment: @Winther Do you mean the solution can be approximated by $u(t,x)$ on the form we have? In other words, the numerical solution captures the basic properties of the exact solution?

Comment: I would say the numerical solution *is* the exact solution (if you computed it correctly). The form you have put up seems to be a good approximation for this solution (but it's only an approximation) and the reason it is a decent approximation comes from the fact I mention above.

Comment: @Winther OK. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: btw I double checked your numerical solution. I get what looks like exactly  the same solution as you have found (see [this plot](http://folk.uio.no/hansw/pdesol.png)) so it looks like you have computed it correctly (or we have made the same mistake:).

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your kind help.